# handle ftp errors in r code

Tags: r

I have a bunch of ftp site that I would like to automatically retrieve data using rCurl getURL function.

I am doing this:

First I have a vector of url sides like this:

```
 sites<-c("ftp.test1.com", "ftp.test2.com", "ftp.test3.com")
 for (i in 1:length(sites)) {
  data<-getURL(sites[i], userpwd="id:passwd")

  <here I have code to insert this data to db>
}
```

up until here it works. But sometimes, I can have time out from the ftp site. If there is time out this code breaks. How I could handle if there is a time out or authentication error. I like to continue to process other fpt sites and log the problem with the ftp site that is having problems. Any idea, how I would do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by `the code breaks` you mean that the code raises an R error, you can use `tryCatch` to capture the error. Then, in stead of raising an error, you can gracefully deal with the issue, e.g. just omit that data, or try and build a new connection.

Comment: this comes up alot. If there is an error with some data or empty data frame assignment, rather than continouing, the whole program shuts down. Is there good example of this sort of problem I that I can take look at using tryCatch?